# Get Percentage of 2 decimals

Tags: php, formatting, numbers

Seems simple but can't figure this out:

```
$goal = 10.000;
$actual = 55.32;

$percentChange = number_format(( $actual / $goal) * 100, 2);

echo  $percentChange;
```

**OUTPUT**
553.20

**WANTED OUTPUT**
0.5532

The problem occurs only when output is less than 1 0.XXXX code is working fine from 1 above.

Comment: Try dividing by 10, not multiplying by 100. And you'd want to round to 4, not 2.

Comment: ^ plus replace `, 2` with `, 4` because you want 4 decimal places, not 2.

Comment: The problem occurs only when output is less than 1 0.XXXX code is working fine from 1 above.

Comment: What do your input values represent? The math for calculating a percent works out.

Comment: Then you probably want to switch the number_format if it's greater or less than 1. If the number is correct for above 1 but not below, when you disregard the 100 multiplication, then you may want to recheck your math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dot in `$goal` variable as is taking it as **10** with **4 decimals**

Change this:

```
 $goal = 10.000;
 $actual = 55.32;

 $percentChange = number_format(( $actual / $goal) * 100, 2);

 echo  $percentChange;
```

To this:

```
 $goal = 10000;
 $actual = 55.32;

 $percentChange = number_format(( $actual / $goal) * 100, 4);

 echo  $percentChange;
```